How to add filters to column headers in the pivot sheet using Spire.Xls package in C#
To add filters to each column headers in the pivot sheet in the excel automatically via c# code using Spire.Xls package.
PivotField r1 = pt.PivotFields["Invoice Type"] as PivotField;
r1.Axis = AxisTypes.Row;
r1.RepeatItemLabels = true;
r1.Subtotals = SubtotalTypes.None;
pt.Options.RowHeaderCaption = "Invoice Type";

here i have created a pivot field which gets added in Rows in pivot table getting displayed in the pivot sheet as column headers and I need filters for the same
PivotField r1 = pt.PivotFields["Invoice Type"] as PivotField;
r1.Axis = AxisTypes.Row;
r1.RepeatItemLabels = true;
r1.Subtotals = SubtotalTypes.None;
pt.Options.RowHeaderCaption = "Invoice Type";

foreach (var field in pt.RowFields)
{
    PivotReportFilter filter = new PivotReportFilter(field.Name, true);
    pt.ReportFilters.Add(filter);
} 

field.Name - doenot have a definition for Name

You can now add filters to the row or column fields in a pivot table with Spire.XLS.
Here is an example of adding a filter to a row field:
using Spire.Xls;
using Spire.Xls.Core.Spreadsheet.PivotTables;

namespace AddRowFilter
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create an object of the Workbook class
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            // Load an Excel file
            workbook.LoadFromFile("Sample.xlsx");

            // Get the first worksheet
            Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            // Get the first pivot table
            XlsPivotTable pt = sheet.PivotTables[0] as XlsPivotTable;


            // Add a value filter to the first row field in the pivot table
            pt.RowFields[0].AddValueFilter(PivotValueFilterType.GreaterThan, pt.DataFields[0], 5000, null);
            // Or add a label filter to the first row field in the pivot table
            //pt.RowFields[0].AddLabelFilter(PivotLabelFilterType.Equal, "Mike", null);

            // Calculate the pivot table data
            pt.CalculateData();

            // Save the resulting file
            workbook.SaveToFile("AddRowFilter.xlsx", FileFormat.Version2016);
            workbook.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

Here is an example of adding a filter to a column field:
using Spire.Xls;
using Spire.Xls.Core.Spreadsheet.PivotTables;

namespace AddColumnFilter
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create an object of the Workbook class
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            // Load an Excel file
            workbook.LoadFromFile("Sample.xlsx");

            // Get the first worksheet
            Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

            // Get the first pivot table
            XlsPivotTable pt = sheet.PivotTables[0] as XlsPivotTable;

            // Add a label filter to the first column field in the pivot table
            pt.ColumnFields[0].AddLabelFilter(PivotLabelFilterType.Equal, "Laptop", null);
            // Or add a value filter to the first column field in the pivot table
            // pt.ColumnFields[0].AddValueFilter(PivotValueFilterType.Between, pt.DataFields[0], 5000, 10000);


            // Calculate the pivot table data
            pt.CalculateData();

            // Save the resulting file
            workbook.SaveToFile("AddColumnFilter.xlsx", FileFormat.Version2016);
            workbook.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

For more detailed information, you can visit this article:
C#: Add Filters to Pivot Tables in Excel
